# C alculating flux using the divergence theorem when the divergence is 0

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, vector-analysis, surface-integrals

I calculated the divergence of my vector field $\langle x^2 + y^2, y^2 + z^2, 1 − 2xz − 2yz\rangle$ to be $0$. The flux is meant to be over the unit hemisphere. If I do use the divergence theorem, wouldn't I get a triple integral of 0 over the unit hemisphere? In that case the flux would be zero, but I have been told that the plux is equal to $\pi$. I'm unsure how to get this. The orientation is positive upwards.

Comment: Is it just over the actual hemisphere, or the hemisphere with the disk in the middle as well? The divergence theorem result will include the disk. You can still use the divergence theorem to get the integral over the actual hemisphere, because it says integral over hemisphere+integral over disk=integral of divergence over volume, so you can subtract off the integral of the disk (perhaps easier to compute!) from the divergence integral.

Comment: @Ian No 'perhaps' about it, given what the $z$-component is in the $z=0$ plane...

Comment: So the divergence theorem gave me the flux through the hemisphere excluding the disk? @Ian

Comment: Also what does it mean when they say the upward-pointing
unit normal is chosen at each point? @Ian

Comment: The divergence theorem is giving you the outward flux over the entire hemisphere, including the disk. Note that on the hemisphere itself, the upward flux is the outward flux, but on the disk the outward flux is the downward flux.

Comment: okay then im still unsure as to why the flux will be the double integral over the disk only? @Ian

Comment: if the divergence theorem included the disk then wouldnt that be the end of the question? @Ian

Comment: The volume integral of the divergence is the sum of the outward flux through the actual hemisphere and the outward flux through the central disk. You apparently want the upward flux through the actual hemisphere without the flux through the disk (maybe I'm wrong). So you compute the volume integral of the divergence. What you have is off by the outward flux integral through the central disk. Directly calculate that and then subtract it off.